# How to combine multiple columns in excel -- stack columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
1   6  11
2   7  12
3   8  13
4   9  14
5  10  15
```

I have three columns in excel-- how do I combine such that all values are in one column

column 1

column 2

column 3

Thankyou :)

Final output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: `TOCOL()` should do that for you --> `=TOCOL(D14:F18,3,1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel formula - How to stack values from 10 or multiple columns into 1 column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525557/excel-formula-how-to-stack-values-from-10-or-multiple-columns-into-1-column)

Answer (score 3):

With `MS365` try using `TOCOL()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E1` --> **Exclusively Applicable To MS365**

```
=TOCOL(A1:C5,3,1)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `G1` this also can be used considering the fact that there are only three columns --> **Exclusively Applicable To MS365**

```
=VSTACK(A1:A5,B1:B5,C1:C5)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `I1` --> **Applicable To Excel 2019+ onwards,**

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,A1:A5,B1:B5,C1:C5)&"</s></t>","//s")
```

---

• Formula used in cell `K1` --> **Applicable To Excel 2010+ onwards**

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$5,
MOD(ROW(A1)-1+ROWS($A$1:$C$5),ROWS($A$1:$C$5))+1,
INT((ROW(A1)-1)/ROWS($A$1:$C$5))+1)
```

---